# How can I use a list comprehension to set colors?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, list-comprehension

Consider the following bar plot.
[image]

In order to have bars higher than 40000 colored in blue and bars lower than 40000 colored in red, I tried to use the following list comprehension:

```
df.count().plot(kind = 'bar', color = ['powderblue' if df[e].count() > 40000 else 'red' for e in df])
```

- `df` is my dataframe
- `df[e].count()` should return the number of non-NaN values contained in each column

However matplotlib returns this instead: 
[image]

... all red.

It's all the more strange that the very same list comprehension works perfectly well when taken separately:

```
colors = ['powderblue' if df[e].count() > 40000 else 'red' for e in df]
Print(colors)

powderblue
powderblue
powderblue
powderblue
powderblue
powderblue
powderblue
powderblue
red
...
```

Can someone please explain me what I'm missing here ?

EDIT: the data frame looks like this:

```
    code    url   creator  quantity   brands
1     3     NaN      B       0.5        Ta  
2     NaN   Se       A       3.8        De 
3     6     Th       D       6.8        NaN
4     2     Fr       C       NaN        Be 
5     1     Il       F       2.4        Pm
...
```

MCVE:

```
# creating an array of shape 10x10
array = np.random.choice(10, size = (10, 10))

# transforming it in a dataframe and replacing zeros and ones by NaN
df = pd.DataFrame(array).replace((0,1), np.nan)
print(df)

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   8.0     NaN     6   5   8.0     NaN     NaN     2.0     NaN     7.0
1   7.0     8.0     7   8   9.0     8.0     9.0     8.0     8.0     5.0
2   9.0     8.0     7   7   6.0     8.0     8.0     7.0     8.0     6.0
3   4.0     4.0     3   3   3.0     5.0     4.0     2.0     6.0     4.0
4   5.0     7.0     4   9   2.0     8.0     NaN     7.0     NaN     5.0
5   7.0     6.0     6   7   NaN     5.0     NaN     5.0     4.0     3.0
6   6.0     8.0     5   5   4.0     NaN     3.0     NaN     9.0     2.0
7   9.0     5.0     4   3   NaN     7.0     6.0     4.0     8.0     NaN
8   NaN     2.0     8   8   7.0     7.0     2.0     9.0     3.0     5.0
9   3.0     9.0     6   3   9.0     NaN     9.0     7.0     2.0     8.0

# creating a working list comprehension
colors = ['blue' if df[e].count() > 8 else 'red' for e in df]
print(colors)

'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue'

# plotting the dataframe using the same list comprehension
df.count().plot(kind = 'bar', color = colors)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of what your data frame looks like?

Comment: Sure, I just edited my question

Comment: Could you try to find a [mcve]?  I just tried your code with the dataframe you pasted, using `df.count().plot(kind = 'bar', color = ['powderblue' if df[e].count() > 4 else 'red' for e in df])` instead of 40000, and got four reds and one blue "creator", as expected.

Comment: Thank you@ DSM. I just updated the question with a mcve.

Comment: Your code works for me. What version of matplotlib and pandas are you using?

Comment: @DavidG That's strange. 0.20.0 for pandas and 2.0.2 for matplolib.

Comment: I just installed the latest version of both and it turns out colors are now displayed correctly ! Thank you for your suggestion @DavidG

Comment: @solub No problem. FYI it is probably best to post the solution as an answer to this question and then accept it, rather than edit the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matplotlib version (2.0.2) I was using was outdated and somehow prevented the list comprehension to run correctly. Version 2.1.0 solved the issue.

Thanks DavidG for the suggestion.

[image: the list comprehension works perfectly fine with the lastest version of matplotlib (2.1.0)]